# Woocommerce Show Variation Thumbnail on Catalogue/Shop Page

Tags: woocommerce

Is there anyway to add variation thumbnail on shop/catalogue page of each variant product?

Example: 
Red size: Small, Med, Large
Blue size: Small, Med,Large

I use the following code to get all thumbnails listed. But it doesn't make any sense to have all 3 red and blue thumbnails listed, they are all the same image. There should only be 2 thumbnail images instead of 6.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'loop_display_variation_attribute_and_thumbnail' );
function loop_display_variation_attribute_and_thumbnail() {
    global $product;
    if( $product->is_type('variable') ){
        foreach ( $product->get_visible_children() as $variation_id ){
            // Get an instance of the WC_Product_Variation object
            $variation = wc_get_product( $variation_id );

            // Get "color" product attribute term name value
            $color = $variation->get_attribute('color');

            if( ! empty($color) ){
                // Display "color" product attribute term name value
                echo $color;

                // Display the product thumbnail with a defined size (here 30 x 30 pixels)
                echo $variation->get_image( array(30, 30) );
            }
        }
    }
}
```